# Display custom attribute on "Customer's Dashboard " and "Edit Account" in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, custom-attributes

I know this might have been probably asked before but through out the net I didn't get a single proper working post to my problem. Hence thought of asking it myself.

I have created a custom field "Company Name" for my Customer's registration form. Its showing on registration form as well as customers grid at admin side. I would also like to see this field in "Customer's Dashboard" and "Edit Account Information" Section at front-end.

I have followed the below solution, but I didn't get it. I am a beginner in Magento 2.0
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125367/45181

Here is my source code:

**InstallData.php**

```
namespace MyModules\CustomerMarketingFields\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_name",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Company Name",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => '',
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => "",
        "is_used_in_grid" => true,
        "is_visible_in_grid" => true,
        "is_filterable_in_grid" => true,
        "is_searchable_in_grid" => true

    ));

    $regulation   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company_name");

    $regulation = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'company_name');
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $regulation->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $regulation->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

**customer_account_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_form_additional_info_customer" template="MyModules_CustomerMarketingFields::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**additionalinfocustomer.phtml**

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>

<p>
<div class="field company_name required">
    <label for="company_name" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Company Name') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo __('Company Name') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
    </div>
</div>
</p></fieldset>
```

Please I would really appreciate if some one can tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this i also had the same issue.. Solved it by following this link. [http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, finally

**Step 1:**
Create configuration files for **Customer's Dashboard** and **Edit My Account** pages.

**Step 2:**
Use the below code in your phtml files to get the customer custom attributes .

```
$objm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $customerSession = $objm->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
 if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
 {
 echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute();
 // use your custom attribute name to get the value.
 }
```