# Add customer custom attribute to customer grid for searching and filtering

Tags: customer, magento-2.1.3

I have Magento 2.1.3 and have added a custom field in to the admin area of customers which works nicely, however I am now trying to add that field to the customer grid view in the admin area so we can search and filter by that field.

I have got the column to appear in the customer grid view but the data values for that field/record are not showing, the column is just blank.

'I think' I have to add to indexer.xml, but when I do a reindex I get an SQL error - details below...

Here is my Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace custom\CustomerPut\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * Customer setup factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
 */
private $customerSetupFactory;
/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
{
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}
/**
 * Installs DB schema for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
    $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "customer_account");

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "customer_account",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Customer Account",
        "input"    => "text",
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "is_used_in_grid" => true,
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));

    $customer_account   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "customer_account");

    $customer_account = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_account');
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $customer_account->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);

    $customer_account->save();



    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Here is my etc/indexer.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
<indexer id="customer_grid" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
    <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
        <field name="customer_account" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
    </fieldset>
</indexer>
</config>
```

When I rebuild in the index I get the following SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.customer_account'
```

What am I missing?
Any help would be most appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Check the below link. It may help you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139479/display-custom-attribute-on-customers-dashboard-and-edit-account-in-magent.

Comment: Thank you but no I dont need to display it on frontend. I have the column visible in the backend on the Customer grid view, but the values stored in that field are not displaying

Comment: "is_used_in_grid" => true,
    "is_visible_in_grid" => true,
     "is_filterable_in_grid" => true,
      "is_searchable_in_grid" => true.              Try to add them in installData.php

Comment: thanks yeah i did notice those and added those in but still no joy for unfortunately. do i need to worry about indexer.xml?

Comment: can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I have managed to get my field to display in the admin grid now by adding customer_listing.xml to view/adminhtml/ui_component but the field is blank and is not displaying the data saved in the field. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Having the same requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Had the some issue and couldn't figure it out. Did it this way in the end:

http://undefined.gr/site/2017/05/22/magento-2-1-creating-a-new-customer-attribute-and-adding-it-to-the-customers-grid/